# Is this a context free or context sensitive language?

Tags: context-free-language

I am studying Formal Languages and Automata Theory, and I have a question about a problem inside the book that is not answered in it. the question is:

Is this language Context Free, Regular or Context Sensitive?

L={a^i b^j c^k|i<=j or j<=i , j=k}

Answer (score 0):

It's context-free. It can be specified with the following CFG:

```
S -> AX
A -> aA
A -> epsilon
X -> bXc
X -> epsilon
```

The A state accepts as many `a`s as you need. X generates `b` and `c` in equal quantity. Therefore this CFG specifies the language L.

Answer (score -1):

It's context sensitive.

Not Regular : We have to remember the number of occurences of b or c which finite state machine can't.

Not context free as if we apply pumping lemma you will see we have more b's than c's after pushing b for a string like `a^{2}b^{2} b^{n-4}b^{2}c^{n}`.

So it is context sensitive.

Comment: ohh yes...actually some people say that it is DFCL because there is only one comparison j=k and it doesn't matter if i is equal to j or not

Comment: @a_m.: Really if you think well enough you will see that it is context sensitive. You can try reading a book relaly. My answer is correct.

Comment: @a_m.: applied this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages

Comment: @a_m.: you understand?

Comment: The language is really not context-free. The application of the pumping lemma, however, is much more complicated than @coderredoc explains. The lemma only proves something, if for ALL POSSIBLE factorizations the pumping leads out of the language, not just for one example factorization. Therefore a careful case analysis is needed here. In the example string one could pump b in oe factor, c in the other, and stay in the language.